# How to define Eloquent relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two models - the **User** model and the **Movie** model for the following tables

The **user** table has the following columns

- id
- age

The **movie** table has the following columns

- id
- min_age

How do I define a relationship on the **User** model such that for each user, I am able to get all the movies which follow the constraint:

**Movie.min_age <= User.age**

I know that I can just query the Movie model and get all movies having min_age less than or equal to the age of the User. My question is that how can this be achieved by defining an **Eloquent relationship** inside the **User** model using the functions like **hasMany()** or **belongsToMany()**?

Comment: Have you defined a `belongsToMany` relationship between users and movies?

Comment: @RossWilson No I haven't.

Comment: Use [query scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#query-scopes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a user can watch many movies. At the same time a movie can be watched from many users at the same time.

On User.php

```
public function movies(){

   return $this->hasMany(Movie::class);
 }
```

On Movie.php

```
public function users(){
  return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

To get what you are looking for through relationship you do something like this;

Let us say that you have a auth system set as well.

```
$user = Auth::user();

$getMovies = $user->movies()->where('min_age','<=',$user->age)->get();
```

Comment: Thanks. I was under the impression that relationships worked through primary and foreign keys only and it seems I was wrong.